# How setText to custom dialog from one class in others?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, dialog

I have created a dialog class that i would like to use in several other classes and depending in what class they should display different info. I have no problem displaying the dialog itself with working button and an already set text from the xml. But when i try to set my own text with setText the app crashes and give me java.lang.NullPointerException. What can be the problem ?

Here is my custom dialog class

```
public class CustomDialogInfoClass extends Dialog implements     View.OnClickListener {
Button ok;
TextView myTextView;
Typeface myFont;


public CustomDialogInfoClass(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_not_demo);
        CustomDialogInfoClass c = new CustomDialogInfoClass(getContext());

        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        myTextView = (TextView) c.findViewById(R.id.textViewDialog);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

        myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
        ok.setTypeface(myFont);
        myTextView.setTypeface(myFont);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnOk:
                dismiss();
                break;
            default:
        }
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

And here is my main where I try to call it;

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView myTextview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomDialogInfoClass dialogInfo = new CustomDialogInfoClass(this);
    myTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDialog);

    myTextview.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"); <----Null.pointer error 
    dialogInfo.show();
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/diabox"
    android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textViewDialog"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Test text" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ok"
    android:id="@+id/btnOk"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

and logcat if that helps?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.name.appname/com.example.name.appname.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2221)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5064)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:613)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.name.appnamne.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6084)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5064)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:613)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you want to create a DialogFragment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shouldn't access your text view from activity

in your dialog you have this constructor

`public CustomDialogInfoClass(Context context) {
    super(context);
}`

so make this one too:

```
public CustomDialogInfoClass(Context context,String text) {
    CustomDialogInfoClass(context);
    this.text = text;
}
```

and make a String field in your dialog class

```
String text;
```

and setup your TextView  in the dialog

```
myTextView = (TextView) c.findViewById(R.id.textViewDialog);
myTextView.setText(text);
```

and in your activity pass your text here:

```
CustomDialogInfoClass c = new CustomDialogInfoClass(getContext(), "MY TEXT");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! I had to keep the ` super(context)` instead of your sollution for it to work and `getContext()` couldn't be found and neither get ApplicationContext. But `(this, "my text)` worked perfectly. Also you wrote "you shouldn't access your text view from activity" is this something in general or just in my case and similar wher you have constructors? Thansk again!

Comment: @halalbin Sajed's comments about accessing views is very general. You can only access a view within the hierarchy where it lives. When your text view is in a dialog, you need to access it from the dialog's view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of the TextView from inside your dialog during onCreate method.

To pass parameters to the dialog the proper way would be to have a static method in you Dialog class that return a new instance of the Object.
This method can accept paramaters and put them in a Bundle. Now you can set this bundle as argument to the created Dialog

```
public static YourDialog getInstance(String par1, int par2) {

    YourDialog dialog = new YourDialog()

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(TAG, par1);
    bundle.putInt(TAG2, par2);
    dialog.setArguments(bundle);

    return dialog;
}
```

At this point in the OnCreate method of your dialog you can get the Bundle using getArguments() using the tag you provided before and set your TextView

Once you have done in your MainActivity get an Instance of the dialog and call show() to show it

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried this but i didn't quite understand it, got a lot of of errors and varibles that couldn't be resolved. I' maybe give it trie tomorrow during the day. But is this a better way to do it or is just that you think is better? Is you maybe understans i've beeing coding in Java for about 1 month, But thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: this is the proper way